# How to Host Lumen by Laravel on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to host my portfolio website on Google Cloud App Engine build in Lumen by Laravel.

As you know that Lumen uses this command `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` to serve while Laravels use `php artisan serve`

Here's my App.yaml

```
runtime: php73

env_variables:
  APP_KEY: "Already Get this from ENV"
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
```

Right now am getting `HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: Is this pre-deployment? Or post-deployment? What is the HTTP url you are putting into your browser when this fails? I ask, because it's possible to test [locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally), or [online](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/testing-and-deploying-your-app#testing-on-app-engine). Keep in mind that your Yaml is mostly the online configuration.

Comment: As am using google cloud app engine so it automatically generates the URL.
That is https://sho9800.uc.r.appspot.com/

Comment: I thought you were using "localhost" above. If you are testing after deployment (online), the App Engine logs will reveal more about the issue for the 500 error. You can navigate to StackDriver Logging > Logs Viewer, or Trace > Overview, or use [logs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/)/[tail](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/tail) command. Otherwise, you may need to open a support ticket since there's too many possibilities and the problem needs to be narrowed down a bit more.